# iOS 11.2.2 simulator is not listing in XCode Components

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The latest iOS version 11.2.2 was released on [January 8, 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history)

But its still not reflecting in XCode components, what could be the reason ? Is Apple not yet released those simulators ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no point releases for simulators. There is an 11.2, 11.1, 11.0, etc. simulator but you will never see an 11.2.1 or 11.2.2 simulator.

The only exception I've ever seen is a 10.3.1 simulator (but no 10.3 simulator).

Comment: Is its so, thanks for the information. But I couldn't even see 11.2 as of now, any reason for that ? FYR: I have added screenshot.

Comment: 11.2 is part of Xcode 9.2 so there no need to download it separately.

Comment: Thank you, now its clear, but why I was asking in I had a crash specifically in 11.2.2 version, But I don't have any iOS device with that version, so I has raised this question. So I think I can't expect specific version(11.2.2) in simulator expect exception :-). Finally I installed the version in my device and tested :-)